# Can I open photos straight from the photo gallery into my app?

Tags: ios, photo-gallery

I have an app that allows the user to select photos from their library and then use them but I am looking for a way they can be opened straight from the Photos app that list all the photos.

It would be in the same way that when you click to share a photo you can use services like Twitter, Facebook and Email them etc. I have looked into assigning the app the document type so that the images can be opened from say an email attachment through the quick look but I am wanting it to be accessible from the photo gallery itself.

Is this even possible or are apps not aloud to be listed in the share list?

Comment: Please don't sign your questions. That is considered unnecessary on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Isn't this what extensions are all about?

Comment: Just trying to be friendly, thats all. Looking into extensions now, thanks